# Why does my outlet have two white wires on the neutral side and one "neutral" wire is hot?

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral

The breaker for my microwave tripped and when I turned the breaker back on it tripped again after using the microwave again. I tested the microwave in another outlet and it works fine. I went to replace the outlet and I found a black wire, two white on the same side, and ground. I turned off the breaker and tested the wires only to find that one white wire still has 120v where all other wires are dead. Why is that wire supplying voltage on the neutral side?

Comment: Are there other things on this circuit? Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Is the breaker that trips a simple breaker or does it include AFCI or GFCI?

Comment: It sounds like some other circuit is poaching neutral from this circuit.  Also, are there red wires in the box?

Comment: [the red wire?](https://cheezburger.com/8132521216)

Comment: How old is your house?

Comment: Your meter could be reading a "phantom voltage". Also, if that white wire is the neutral of another energized device nearby, then you are interrupting that return and reading line voltage through that other device.

Answer (score 1):

You could be dealing with 1/2 switched receptacles. 1 part of the receptacle is controlled by a wall switch that will allow table lamps and etc to controlled by that wall switch. My whole house is wired that way. Half the receptacle is wired always hot and the other is controlled by a switch. Check it out.